# Is proving the existence of a model for some theory strictly stronger than defining a model?

Tags: logic, model-theory

If yes, what's an example where we can prove the existence of a model but can't construct one? (Meta-theory: ZFC)

Comment: It's clear what you mean by "prove the existence of a mode", but it's not so clear what you mean by "construct" or "define" a model. Can you be more precise?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Just like in everyday math, use model construction method (like [these](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modeltheory-fo/#Const:~:text=4.-,Three%20useful%20constructions,-A%20construction%20is)) to give a model, rather than just proof the existence.

Comment: I don't think there is a clear distinction between "construct" and "prove the existence of" in everyday math either. If you provided an explicit list of "constructiom methods", the question could become meaningful. But in the meantime, maybe this will satisfy you: Suppose $T$ has a model. Then $T$ is consistent. Then we can use the [Henkin construction](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Henkin_construction) to build an "explicit" model of $T$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh, I forgot the Henkin construction. That solves my question. Thanks! For everyday math, don't we sometimes just prove the existence by contradiction without finding an actual example?

Comment: Yes, it could be possible to use non-constructive reasoning to prove the existence of a model. But the exact meaning of "constructive reasoning" is a little tricky to pin down. For example, in my comment about the Henkin construction, I put "explicit" in scare quotes because the theorem that every consistent theory has a model requires the axiom of choice - so is the Henkin construction really constructive? (The axiom of choice is not necessary when the language is countable or, more generally, well-orderable.)

Comment: "The axiom of choice is not necessary when the language is countable."  I just checked a proof [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/03%3A_Completeness_and_Compactness/3.02%3A_Completeness#:~:text=We%20can%20do,of%20countable%20sets.). The statement there right below (3.2.7) "We can do this as L′ is countable, being a countable union of countable sets" needs AC, at least a weak version, aka countable choice. Can you give me a proof where AC is totally avoided?

Comment: You're right that ZF fails to prove "a countable union of countable sets is countable", but the only time you need choice in the proof is to choose a bijection with $\omega$ for each countable set. If you are handed countable many countable sets *together with* bijections to $\omega$, then ZF proves their union is countable (because ZF proves $\omega\times\omega$ is countable). This is the situation with the set of $L'$-sentences: ZF can prove that each of the sets you want to take the union of has a canonical bijection to $\omega$, so it can prove the set of $L'$-sentences is countable.